# Ask user to write the correct file name if he wrote wrong

Tags: python

I want to upload some files using my upload function below.

I am asking user to write the name of the files that he wants to upload.

But I am trying to do some kind of validation before, if the user writes a filename that does not exist I want to show a message "The file you selected does not exist, please try again" and I want to ask again user to write same filename so he can write correctly. Do you see how can I achieve this?

```
def upload(filename):
    if(os.path.exists(filename)):
        # here I do the upload
    else:
        print "The file you selected does not exist, please try again"
        # here I want to ask user again for the field that he filled wrong
        # but this needs to be dynamic (first, second or third)
        uploadToS3(input("Select the first/second/third file:"))
print

raw_input("Press enter to transfer the files...")

upload(input("Select the first file:"))
upload(input("Select second file:"))
upload(input("Select third file:"))
```

Comment: What is meant by `"but this needs to be dynamic (first, second or third)"`? Can you elaborate?

Comment: Do you mean that if the first input asked for the second file, then the second input generated by the function should ask for the second file and so on?

Comment: Your code will not work because you are using both raw input and input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My answer using recursion is:

```
def upload(prompt):
    filename = input(prompt) #ask for filename using the given prompt
    if(os.path.exists(filename)):
        uploadToS3(filename)
    else:
        print "The file you selected does not exist, please try again"
        upload(prompt) #Repeat this function if the use did not give valid input
print

raw_input("Press enter to transfer the files...")

upload("Select the fist file:")
upload("Select second file:")
upload("Select third file:")
```

The second input will display the exact same message as the first one.

Answer (score 3):

Since you step through `upload()` file by file you can validate them one at a time in the function by locking them in a loop.  `return` out of the loop (and function) once it successfully uploads:

```
def upload(filename):
    while True:
        if(os.path.exists(filename)):
            # here I do the upload
            return
        else:
            print "The file you selected does not exist, please try again"
            filename = input("Select the first/second/third file:")
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd probably do something like the following:

```
def get_filename(prompt):
    while True:
        fn = raw_input(prompt)
        if os.path.exists(fn): return fn
        print("The file you selected does not exist, please try again")


uploadToS3(get_filename("Select the fist file:"))
uploadToS3(get_filename("Select second file:"))
uploadToS3(get_filename("Select third file:"))
```

This also gets rid of your `upload` function.

This approach defines a function called `get_filename` that accepts as an argument, the prompt you want to present.

The prompt is presented and input collected.

If the input filename exists, it's returned to `uploadToS3`.

If the input filename *doesn't* exist, a message is printed saying so, and the prompt re-issued, input re-collected, etc.

Answer (score 1):

What about something like this? It is a fast hack, but might work .

```
def upload(filename):
    if(os.path.exists(filename)):
        # here I do the upload
        return True
    else:
        print "The file you selected does not exist, please try again"
        # here I want to ask user again for the field that he filled wrong
        # but this needs to be dynamic (first, second or third)
        uploadToS3(input("Select the first/second/third file:"))
print
return False

def read_user_input(prompt):
    oper_status = upload(input(prompt))
    while oper_status is not True:
        oper_status = upload(input(prompt))


raw_input("Press enter to transfer the files...")

read_user_input(input("Select the fist file:"))
read_user_input(input("Select second file:"))
read_user_input((input("Select third file:"))
```

Answer (score 1):

try a simple while loop. The while loop will remain True while the entered filename doesn't exist. Once the user enters a file name that exist it will break the while loop and continue on to the uploading section. Of course you should adapt the programming logic to fit your needs.

```
def upload(filename):
    while True:
        if not(os.path.exists(filename)):
            print "The file you selected does not exist, please try again"
        else:
            #upload stuff
            break
```

Comment: Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others.